# What does the <number> mean in EXISTS (SELECT <number> FROM <table>?

Tags: sql, db2

I'm somewhat confused about the following SQL from a script I need to change:

```
...
WHERE
    EXISTS (
    SELECT
        737
    FROM
        <table_name>
    WHERE...
```

What does the 737 portion of the SELECT-statement mean? It can't be a column name (AFAIK DB2 does not support this), neither a column index (table has "just" 74 columns). Could this be a row counter, meaning "give me exactly 737 rows"? Wouldn't make sense at all here...

Comment: Just a dummy value, EXISTS doesn't care. (However, bad idea to choose such a value, too many code readers will be confused. Stick to `*` or `1`.)

Comment: The EXISTS result is TRUE if the subquery returns one row or more. If no row is returned, the result is FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 373 FROM <table_name>
```

will return exactly one row with one unnamed column and that cell has the value "373".

Since it is wrapped inside the EXISTS statement which will check if ANY result is coming from the inner query, it does not matter what is returned there.
From a clean code perspective, it is a bad choice to take such a number as it implies a meaning to readers - which is not there. Instead, one should say SELECT * or SELECT 1 instead.

Comment: How many rows returned depends on the number of rows in the table, it could be none, or a million. Also, there are no _cells_ in SQL.

Comment: The select statement I wrote in the example will return exactly one row.
I only took the sub-select since it was not clear to the author what SELECT 373 will do.

Comment: How do you know the table contents?

Comment: This select of my reply will always return 373, no matter what your table design and entries look like.

Answer (score 0):

To make it understand that SELECT clause of the SELECT statement inside a EXISTS / NO EXISTS operator, I usually write, into the SELECT clause the expression 1/0...

Usually evaluating this mathematical formula should raise an error and the query stop.... Which is not the case in some good RDBMS like MIcrosoft SQL Server :

```
SELECT *
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT 1/0 
              FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T2
              WHERE  T.TABLE_NAME = T2.TABLE_NAME
                AND  T.TABLE_SCHEMA <> T2.TABLE_SCHEMA)
```

If you execute the subquery without the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT 1/0 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T2
```

You'll have an error :

*Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Divide par zero.*

Which is not the case for the first query, that proove that SELECT clause has not been evaluated...